# dual boot, grub rescue, all partitions unknown filesystem

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grubrescue

I am stuck with grub rescue.

I have a dual-boot with a Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04. Now when I try to boot my laptop, it enters grub rescue mode.

I tried 'ls' commond:

```
grub rescue > ls
```

The results are as followed:

```
(hd0) (hd0,msdos6) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1)
```

Then I tried:

```
grub rescue > ls (hd0)/
grub rescue > ls (hd0,msdos6)/
grub rescue > ls (hd0,msdos5)/
grub rescue > ls (hd0,msdos2)/
grub rescue > ls (hd0,msdos1)/
```

and

```
grub rescue > ls (hd0)/grub
grub rescue > ls (hd0,msdos6)/grub
grub rescue > ls (hd0,msdos5)/grub
grub rescue > ls (hd0,msdos2)/grub
grub rescue > ls (hd0,msdos1)/grub
```

and

```
grub rescue > ls (hd0)/boot/grub
grub rescue > ls (hd0,msdos6)/boot/grub
grub rescue > ls (hd0,msdos5)/boot/grub
grub rescue > ls (hd0,msdos2)/boot/grub
grub rescue > ls (hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub
```

All these commands returned with a result:

```
error: unknown filesystem
```

No linux patition was found ?? What should I do?

Comment: Did you leave Windows 10 fast start on, which is always on hibernation? May be best to see details:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Answer (score 0):

If you have fast boot enabled, disable it and try again, although you might have to reinstall grub

I hope this helps in some way.